# C# - Assigning the result of a boolean expression

Tags: c#

I'm not sure if this is a feature that c# supports, but it is a construct that I use in javascript programming and I am hoping to use the construct with c# if it supports it (.net Framework 3.5).

I have the following working code:

```
if (user.Status == AccountStatus.Active) {
  status = true;
} else {
  status = false;
}
```

I would like to shorten it as follows:

```
status = (user.Status == AccountStatus.Active);
```

In Javascript this will assign the true / false result of the evaluation within the parenthesis. This appears not to work for me in c#, and results in a generic compilation error.

Is there an alternative way to achieve this in a way that is compact?

Comment: Should work with no compilation error

Comment: Your syntax is correct, there must be another reason why this does not work.

Comment: this should works in c#. Is user.Status actually of type AccountStatus (which is an enum i guess?)?

Comment: "results in a generic compilation error." Is that the actual error message? "Generic compilation error"? Do you get a line number?

Comment: I don't think you can use == operator if user.Status isn't of type AccountStatus. == operator would return true/false only when the two operands refer to the same object.

Comment: What is the error ? Do you have the error for the above mentioned line or somewhere else, It would be good to post the exact error message

Comment: did you declare status as bool datatype?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should work fine.

As should:

```
status = user.Status == AccountStatus.Active;
```

Your syntax is correct.

Comment: I think I was unbalancing braces when I made the changes. This does work correctly, thank you. I appreciate the information that the same syntax without the parenthesis should work too.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to successfully execute following

```
bool a = (1 == 0); //returns false
```

and

```
bool a = (1 == 1); //returns true
```